# how to start a process before windows login screen appears

Tags: windows, windows-7, process

I am developing a windows login app (Credential Provider) which need SDK licensing service running for face detection and matching. Now I want to know how i can start that license process before login screen comes up.

Answer (score 1):

create a service and have the provider createinstance call wait until the service is running before returning.  This will delay the logon screen from appearing since the UI will not appear until the provider initializes (if I am reading this correctly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).  This is probably best answered on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a question better asked on StackOverflow (if not already answered), but generally speaking, you want to create a program that runs as a windows service.